# How to flash stock ROM from stock recovery?

Tags: flash, rom

Since I don't have a Windows machine to flash firmware for the Samsung Galaxy J3 2016, I was wondering if it is possible to do it by phone.

I read [here](https://www.google.ro/amp/s/techprolonged.com/upgrade-android-smartphone-firmware-via-tf-card-sd-card/amp/) that you can, and I followed the steps, but it gives me an error (E: footer is wrong, also signature verification failed) when I do it with stock recovery. I renamed the firmware to `update.zip` and put it in the root of the `extcard` and tried to flash it with apply update from external storage.
Any help would be great.